# Java - GUI Add the same button to two different panels

Tags: java, user-interface

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
    public Test() {
        JButton jbt1 = new JButton("Java");
        JButton jbt2 = new JButton("Programming");
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(jbt1);
        p2.add(jbt2);
        p3.add(jbt1);

        add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(p3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public void main(String[] args) {
        Test f = new Test();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The output is:

Java

### Programming

What I am expecting:

Java

Java

### Programming

WHY???????Where is jbt1 in p3 ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java GUI components are laid out hierarchical and each component only can have one parent. By adding a Component into a Container any old parent reference is lost.

Comment: "By adding a Component into a Container any old parent reference is lost."
But the output is p3 does not contain any button

Comment: It should be the btn in p3 from your code that you see with label "Java". As you are using BorderLayout maybe it is not obvious because CENTER and NORTH will be layed out similiar. Change CENTER to EAST and look what happens.

Comment: @Steven Yes p3 contains button jbt1 which is the "Java" button which you have added in the center of the BorderLayout. Your name are confusing because you will have in vertical order p1-p3-p2

Comment: PeterMmm Guillaume Polet Thank you so much! Got it!

Answer (score 2):

but you can:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Action javaAction = new JavaAction();

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
    p1.add(new JButton(javaAction));
    p3.add(new JButton(javaAction));
}

private static final class JavaAction extends AbstractAction {

    JavaAction() {
        super("Java");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // put your code here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The call structure is as follows

```
    p1.add(jbt1); //jbt1 added to p1
    p2.add(jbt2); //jbt2 added to p2
    p3.add(jbt1);  //jbt1 added to p3
```

jbt1 is no longer contained in the same container and hence you get the output you mentioned. Its parent actually changes from p1 to p3.

If you are looking to include buttons with same functionality, you might redirect the action listeners to the same method.

The buttons, however, must be separately created.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the same component to different containers. Only the latest `add` will work. A component can only have a single parent simultaneously. When you add a component to a Container, the Container will automatically remove the component from its previous parent, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a component to one container only, but nothing stops you from creating 2 different buttons and attaching the same eventListener to them so that they respond in the same way when clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

you can't add same button,but you can add same function to those to buttons.. so they act as a same button.

Comment: Please consider being more precise on your answers.